# Alternative to long living token for file download in Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I find the idea of downloadURL that never expire dangerous for certain types of data stored.

Is it possible to download files from Firebase Storage authenticating with the token obtained from Firebase Auth Service?

Comment: What you're describing is what the Firebase Storage client SDK does.  Just use that, and protect your content with security rules that require the user to be authenticated.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your response, but I'm not sure if it solves the problem. I do protect the files the way you describe, but please have a look how file is actually accessed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files. The user receives a long living download url containing a token, and later can be shared and used by anyone. The download url contains a long living token, and there is no requirement to post the short living auth token ie. in headers.